# Tastypie optimization with prefetch_related and ModelResources

Tags: tastypie

I have the following ModelResource:

```
class DivisionsResource(ModelResource):
    plants = fields.ToManyField('plants.api.resources.PlantsResource', 'plant_set', full = True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Division.objects.all().prefetch_related('plant_set')
        allowed_method = ['get']
        filtering = {
                    "name": ('istartswith')
                }


class PlantsResource(ModelResource):
    picture = fields.ToOneField('files.api.resources.PlantPictureResource', 'picture', full=True)
    production_lines = fields.ToManyField('production_lines.api.resources.ProductionLinesResource','productionline_set', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Plant.objects.select_related('picture').all().prefetch_related('productionline_set')
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

However, if I call the "divisions" resource and I look at the SQL queries, it doesn't do the prefetch_related and select_related within the **Plants Resource**. It goes and select the productionline_set and picture for each individual plant, instead of doing a **in** SQL query. Why is that?

I found however that I could do something like this:

```
queryset = Division.objects.all().prefetch_related('plant_set', 'plant_set__picture','plant_set__productionline_set')
```

Do I have to do this for sure in the **Divisions Model**? It will be super long if the "prefetch" and "select_related" are not called when calling from parents..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [django-tastypie-specified-fields](https://github.com/dan-klasson/django-tastypie-specified-fields) (I'm the author). You specify the fields you want to fetch and it will automatically add `only` and `select_related` for you.

However it does not yet support m2m relations and `prefetch_related`. Although that should be fairly trivial to implement, especially for one level in depth. Let me know if you want that and I'll add it.